# INDEX and MATCH with two references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to match two references from sheet2 (column A and B) with sheet1 (column A and first line), and get the correspondent value.

Sheet1:

```
          W    X    Y
 10001    0    2    3
 10002    4    5    6
 10003    7    8    9
 10004    0   11   12
```

Sheet2:

```
        Letter   Value
 10001    W        
 10002    W        
 10003    W         
 10001    X        
 10001    Y        
 10003    Y
```

Sheet2 should be like this:

```
        Letter   Value
 10001    W        0
 10002    W        4
 10003    W        7 
 10001    X        2
 10001    Y        3
 10003    Y        9
```

I´ve tried `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$6,MATCH(Sheet2!A6,Sheet1!A7:B11,0),MATCH(Sheet2!B6,Sheet1!B5:D5,0))`  but it returns N/D

Also: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A1:D6,MATCH(Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!B1:D1,0))`   but it returns the reference value.
Any tips? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below (but, naturally adjust the cell references. I did it on same page, but think it's clear):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH(B8,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for an INDEX MATCH solution but I also have a VLOOKUP array function that will work for n columns and contains all the flexibility of an INDEX MATCH.

[image]